# Ошибка "Local field in class clashes with field of the same name from base class"

Tags: python, django

Сама ошибка:

```
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 114, in apply
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 101, in state_forwards
    state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower, delay=delay)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 158, in reload_model
    self._reload(related_models)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 191, in _reload
    self.apps.render_multiple(states_to_be_rendered)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 308, in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 579, in render
    return type(self.name, bases, body)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 225, in __new__
    base.__name__,
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'coast' in class 'productinorder' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'product'.
```

Классы product и productinorder

```py
class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, verbose_name="Название товара")
    mini_descr = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name="Краткое описание")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_index=True, verbose_name="Полное описание")

    img_src = models.ImageField(db_index=True, verbose_name="Изображение товара")
    img_src1 = models.ImageField(blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Изображение товара1")
    img_src2 = models.ImageField(blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Изображение товара2")
    img_src3 = models.ImageField(blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Изображение товара3")
    img_src4 = models.ImageField(blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Изображение товара4")

    sizes = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25, db_index=True, verbose_name="Размеры")
    coast = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, verbose_name="Цена")

    count = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, verbose_name="Количество на складе")

    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Категория", null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Товар"
        verbose_name_plural="Товары"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_page", args=[self.id])




class productinorder(models.Model):
    Order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Count = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, default=1)

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, verbose_name="Название товара")
    Coast = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, verbose_name="Цена")
```

Comment: Переименовать поле

Comment: А еще привыкайте писать названия классов с большой буквы

Answer (score 1):

Переименуйте поля из `productinorder` в нижний регистр, а также проверьте, что Вы прислали достаточно кода. Гугл говорит, что проблемы в наследовании классов, да и ошибка говорит о наследовании, что `productinorder` основан на `product`

А еще избегайте таких конструкций

> Order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/exceptions/#fielderror

Решение - пересмотреть архитектуру либо наследовать от абстрактной модели, указав это в Meta.

И не надо указывать поля в моделях, в которых уже подразумеваются одноименные поля

```
class A(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    field1 = ...

class B(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    field2 = ...


class C(A, B):
    # модель содержит и 1-е поле и 2-е
    pass
```

Когда приведете больше кода, распишу ваш случай подробнее

И я уверен, что у вас где то есть подобная запись, которая привела к ошибке

```
class SomeModel(product, productinorder):
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Проблема тут вот в чём. В Python-классах существует два вида атрибутов:

1. Атрибуты класса
2. Атрибуты экземпляра

В чём разница между ними, хорошо видно из следующего крохотного примера:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/ipython

class Test():                                                                                
    descr = "Класс"

    def __init__(self):                                                                                 
        self.descr = "Экземпляр"


print(Test.descr)

test = Test()
print(test.descr)
```

Посмотрите на результат работы этой программы.

В этом классе есть два (!!!) атрибута с именем *descr* - атрибут класса и атрибут экземпляра.  Атрибуты экземпляра относятся к разным экземплярам одного класса. И никому жить не мешают.

А вот атрибуты класса становятся становятся доступными в момент **объявления** класса, ещё до того, как был создан хотя бы один экземпляр класса. Т.е. в файле описания модели уже присутствуют и *productinorder.coast* и *product.coast*.

Эта модель передаётся джанго. Джанго собирает какой-то глобальный словарь всех полей таблиц БД. И ему почему-то не нравится, что в Вашей модели есть поля с одинаоквыми именами.

Попробуйте поменять имя *coast* на *coast1* в одном из классов. Посмотрим, что получится... :-)

Comment: А что делать если появляется вот такая хрень: `
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'productinorder' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'product'.`

Comment: такое ощущение, что вы наследуете какуют то модель от одной или обеих указанных в ошибке. Обновите вопрос, добавив модели как либо связзанные с указанными